# Decode JSON with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

Can some one tell why this simple JSON with JqUERY doesn't work for me?

I have this JS code,

```
var jsonParam = <? $json = $_SESSION['searchSess']; echo json_encode($json);?>;
jsonParam = JSON.stringify(jsonParam);
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.post("searching.php?rdr=search", {data: jsonParam,}, function (data){
        alert(data)
    })
});
```

And Here is the PHP code,

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonParam'], true);
var_dump($data);
```

And the response is null or nothing,

can please someone help whats wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

JS:

```
var jsonParam = <? 
    $json = $_SESSION['searchSess']; 
    $json['longitude'] = (string) $json['longitude'];
    $json['latitude'] = (string) $json['latitude'];

    echo json_encode($json);
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $.post("searching.php?rdr=search", {data: jsonParam }, function (data){
        alert(data)
    })
});
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
var_dump($data);
```

I suspect your longitude and latitude fields are not being parsed correctly as floats.

Comment: Nops!! :( it retruns empty too, I dont know why, i'm copying it and paste too and no string returns, brrrrr.

Comment: Updated, try again, I missed the quotes on JSON.parse.

Comment: Ye, I tried that with the quotes before too, but the same :( no stritng returns, I guess its somethings else where, and need to be figure out, does it works when psste it in your server?

Comment: I don't know what your `$_SESSION['searchSess']` is so it's hard for me to tell if it would work :) can you post what you get from doing `echo json_encode($json);` on a blank page?

Comment: This is the result from a blank page, `{"locations":"ARP","pickupair":"JFK","dropoffair":"JFK","pickUpLocation":"John F. Kennedy International Airport (JFK), 144-02 135th Ave, Queens, NY 11436, USA","dropOffLocation":"","pickupmonth":"08","drol":"false","pickupday":"23","pickupyear":"2012","dropoffmonth":"08","dropoffday":"30","dropoffyear":"2012","pickupmin":"09","pickuphour":"00","dropoffpmin":"09","dropoffhour":"00","latitude":4064384.36,"longitude":-7378230.35,"relatitude":0,"relongitude":0,"hourPU":"18","hourDO":"18"}
`

Comment: @thegrede updated again... as far as I can tell from your input, converting longitude and latitude to strings is enough to make it parsable as json, so let's see if this does it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15694/discussion-between-thegrede-and-mahn)

Comment: Ok, I got it work your code above helps me alot of it, I just removed `json_decode()` and it works fine, Thank you for your time Mahn, appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 4):

You want `$_POST['data']`, not `$_POST['jsonParam']`.

Answer (score 3):

`jsonParam` was the JavaScript variable, but it was posted to PHP as `$_POST['data']` since you passed `{data: jsonParam}` into the `$.post`.

```
// Instead:
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], TRUE);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this also returns null, :(

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to see if you got anything, and also look at your page source to be sure that the original `json_encode($json)` printed what it was supposed to.

Comment: Ok, with `var_dump($_POST)` I'm getting this `[data] => {\"locations\":\"ARP\"}`, so how do I perse the array?

Comment: @thegrede `json_decode($_POST['data'], TRUE)` handles that just fine for me, `$data["locations"]` is `ARP`

Comment: But when I do `json_decode($_POST['data'], TRUE)` I'm getting nothing, :(

Comment: @thegrede check the answer I just added.

Answer (score 2):

`{jsonParam: jsonParam,}` Instead of `{data: jsonParam,}`

Answer (score 1):

`$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonParam'], true);` should be `$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);`